# Trouble in importing caffe

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I'm using caffe for deep learning. I installed caffe and it worked fine. But every time I have to append the caffe path to python path. Also, if I change directory, it creates problem. But once I add the path, it works fine. Is there any solution to add this path permanently and make it work globally for whole environment? I am python 2.7 user (Ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `PYTHONPATH` path to `.bashrc`

```
echo -e "export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH" >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
```

Then do:

```
python

import caffe
```

With this, you should be able to import caffe from any path on your system environment.